# Line does not intersect with curve

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, analytic-geometry, quadratics

the line $y=kx+1$ does not intersect with the graph of $y = x^2-3x+5$ at any points

Find the range of possible values for $k$?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
kx+1&=x^2-3x+5\\
0&=x^2-3x-kx+5-1\\
x^2-(3+k)x+4&=0\\
x=\dfrac{(3+k)\pm\sqrt{(3+k)^2-16}}{2}\\
\text{For No Intersection,}\\
(3+k)^2-16<0\\
(3+k)^2<16\\
-4<(3+k)<4\\
-7< k <1\\
\end{align}